# Convert a tree to a list of paths using awk

Tags: awk, path, tree

I have a hierarchical tree of lines:

```
  a
    b
    c
      d
```

I want this tree to be converted into a list of paths such as:

```
a
a/b
a/c
a/c/d
```

Is it possible to solve this problem using `awk`?

Comment: Thank you @lesmana The solution in the linked question is exactly what I was looking for. It is weird that I couldn't find that question after lots of google/stackoverflow searches. Which keywords did you use in your search?

Comment: i searched for "tree to path awk" in duckduckgo.com. also works in my filter bubbled google.com.